# Input in python script imported from GitHub on Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to run a python script on Jenkins

```
import csv
import time
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
search_term = input("Enter the search (Two Words at most) :")
```

Is there a way to get this input in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you would like your Jenkins pipeline to request input and then passing that input to your python code.
I guess then you should remove search_term = input() from your python code and set this as an argument with something like:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="somedescriptionhere")
parser.add_argument('-s', '--search_term', help="sometexthere", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
search_term = args.search_germ
```

then you can put the following on a step on a jenkins pipeline stage:

```
input (id: 'userInput', message: 'Enter the search (Two Words at most) :', parameters: [
    [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition',
    defaultValue: '',
    description: 'Some suitable text for your needs',
    name: 'search_term']
])
sh(script: "timeout --signal=KILL 600 python3 yourpythoncode.py -s ${search_term}")
```

That should ask for input on execution and then pass the value to this python execution.

Comment: what is `parser`?

Comment: I use normally use the argparse parser declaration like in " parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="somedescription")" and then add arguments and return them with "args = parser.parse_args()" like described here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: I've updated my answer reflecting how the argument parsing for the python part as an example